# How to push updated files to GitHub from GitHub Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have tried a lot of things but i keep getting this error:

```
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use
    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

This is my action:

```yaml
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - name: Commit new version
    run: |
      git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot"
      git config --global user.email "41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
      git add -A
      git commit -m "Bumping version number"
      git push
```

Comment: Did you read https://github.com/actions/checkout/tree/v2.4.2#checkout-v2

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes and i followed exactly their steps

Comment: Literally the second paragraph tells you the thing that causes this error and how to fix it.

Comment: You mean this? Checkout HEAD^

Comment: I tried all that but i still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by explicit setting the ref to a branch name. This is not really what i want but will do for now

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      with:
      ref: expo-build
```